# thunderbird mail contacts backup

Tags: backup, thunderbird

Do you know how I can back up my address book in Thunderbird mail. I want to be able to make a back up of my address book in case my computer crashes and I loose all my email contacts. I have managed to back up all my documents but have been unable to work out how to save any information in Thunderbird mail. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily backup your thunderbird profile folder.

Normally it is located in

```
~/.thunderbird/<Profile name>/
```

While in Debian or Ubuntu based build it is located in

```
~/.mozilla-thunderbird<Profile name>.
```

You can just backup the whole directory or if you are not familiar with what exactly is what you want to backup you can try [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/febe/) addon.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to *Export* in the *Tools* menu, when you're in the Address Books view. You can export in the [LDIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) format, or in comma- or tab- separated value files.